# How do I create a List from another List filtered by an object's property in Java?

Tags: java, list

I have an object CalendarEvent

```
public class CalendarEvent {

    LocalDate startDate;
    String clientName;
    Worker worker;
}
```

And I need to find all the objects that have the same startDate. I tried using Maps but they filter by unique keys so it doesn't work for repeated dates

Comment: What is the exact structure at the end ? Grouped by start date, or just filter given ONE date ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Can you add sample input/output and include what you have tried?  It is unclear what you mean by "find all the objects that have the same startDate".

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of those objects in some type of collection called events...

```
    Map<LocalDate, List<CalendarEvent>> mapped = events.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(event -> event.startDate));
```

This will return a map where the keys are the unique start dates and the values are lists of CalenderEvents that have that start date.